# Java Regular Expression Truncate Timestamp value

Tags: java, regex, datetime, timestamp, truncate

```
Input    : 2007-02-09 00:00:00.0

Expected : 2007-02-09
```

How can we truncate `00:00:00.0` using Java Regular Expression ?

Comment: 1) You don't need regular expressions for that. 2) What have you tried?

Comment: Why you would like to use regex. Use `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: tried with Regular expression to truncate the char after space, but i'm not getting my expected

Comment: `input.split("\\s+")[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
String a="2007-02-09 00:00:00.0";
String b=a.split("\\s")[0];
System.out.println(b);         // 2007-02-09
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Q56RMy)

You can also use `SimpleDateForMat`

```
String a = "2007-02-09 00:00:00.0";
Date myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(a);
System.out.println(myDate);
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(myDate);
System.out.println(formattedDate);        // 2007-02-09
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/oqEDIn)

Comment: Thanks, when we try its produce an NullPointerException String publicationDate1 = portfolioDetails.get(4);
  String publicationDate = publicationDate1.split("\\s")[0];
  assetPortfolio.put("publicationdate", publicationDate);

Comment: @Prabu print and check the value of `publicationDate1` I think its `null`

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

> 1. Use `indexOf([space])` and `substring(index+1)` methods (no regex needed).

If you are bent on regex Use:

> 2. `String#replaceAll()` --> capture everything until the space and then replace everything with the captured group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s = "2007-02-09 00:00:00.0";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d*", ""));
```

This will replace the timepart with nothing, so you get the expected result.